# What am I missing ! Timetree query not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH startPath = (event:RESERVATION)-[]->(sd:DAY)<-[:`5`]-(sm:MONTH)<-[:`1`]-(sy:YEAR)<-[:`2016`]-(room:ROOM)
WHERE event.reservationId = 44
RETURN startPath
```

and

```
MATCH endPath   = (event:RESERVATION)-[]->(ed:DAY)<-[:`6`]-(em:MONTH)<-[:`1`]-(ey:YEAR)<-[:`2016`]-(room:ROOM)
    WHERE event.reservationId = 44
    RETURN endPath
```

both return valid paths, but when combined as

```
MATCH startPath = (event:RESERVATION)-[]->(sd:DAY)<-[:`5`]-(sm:MONTH)<-[:`1`]-(sy:YEAR)<-[:`2016`]-(room:ROOM),
      endPath   = (event:RESERVATION)-[]->(ed:DAY)<-[:`6`]-(em:MONTH)<-[:`1`]-(ey:YEAR)<-[:`2016`]-(room:ROOM)
WHERE event.reservationId = 44
RETURN startPath, endPath
```

returns no row !
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The last query requires both `startPath` and `endPath` to end with the same exact `ROOM` node (since they both use the same `room` identifier). Your data probably has no such node.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam 

But the data actually has a common `:ROOM` node

Comment: So, if you modify your 1st 2 queries to return `ID(room)`, do they both return the same value?

Comment: Yes, they return the same value